# Wireless not working on Dell XPS 9320 1360P (Intel 6E AX211 Wireless card) with kernel version 6.1.0-1023-oem on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, 22.04, dell, iwlwifi, xps

Posting here since there are barely any reports on this issue except [this Intel community forum ticket](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Wifi-is-not-working-on-ubuntu/m-p/1532192/thread-id/50189).

In recent days (Oct 16 2023) wireless suddenly stopped working and the "wireless adapter not found" message is printed in Ubuntu's Wireless settings. The above ticket has most of the technical details, but it looks like it's an issue with the recent kernel version 6.1.0-1023-oem and happens on Dell XPS 9320 with Intel 6E AX211 Wireless Card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Upgrading to most recent kernel version fixes the issue as well, so no need to downgrade anymore:

```
# uname -ar
Linux roach 6.1.0-1024-oem #24-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Oct  4 10:18:09 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Original answer:

The current temporary solution until this issue is investigated and resolved is to downgrade the kernel version. The second most recent version I had available was 6.0.0-1021-oem and it resolved the issue. [I followed this guide and it resolved it for me](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/how-to-downgrade-the-kernel-in-ubuntu/).

Note that running Ubuntu updates can re-update your kernel version back.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, fixed it following this [Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lowlatency/+bug/2017790)

In the end, what you do is remove the helper for backport drivers from `Intel backport-iwlwifi` and all installed kernel modules from that backport, and return to the provided OEM code.

To do that, run `Additional Drivers` and put `Do not use the device` on the selection in question. As a side note, for me at shipping this was disabled. It seems thus that with Kernels 6.1 and newer, the installed backport driver has issues. Hit `Apply`.

Next, uninstall all kernel modules. In a terminal type

```
sudo apt remove --purge linux-modules-iwlwifi*
```

Reboot.

I was unsuccessfully waiting for it to work with kernel upgrades. At *-1027 now and before this, it still didn't work.